# OpenCV to find close match for images

Tags: python, c++, image, opencv, image-processing

i want to find closest match of image . for example there is image of car and bike . If given image is of bike .then it should compare given image to stored car and bike and give result according to which ever is **closed base on shape** .

***I wanted to know is it possible to find contour and match with closest one*** .

I tried doing using haar cascade in open cv .By training  car images and bike .
but results were  not correct may be bez of less no of training data.(i dont want to use this )

Comment: I suspect you are going to want to investigate better how machine learning really works.  Its the background that helps create the parameters for things like the haar cascade.   Suggestion for you: Sign up for the Coursera course on Machine Learning by Andrew NG (Stanford) there was one lesson that specifically target how to improve the learning algorithms with a focus on do I need more learning samples, etc....

Comment: thanks zipzit for reply . problem is that i dont have time for that .
there are lot of codes available for face detection and all, where you dont require to go through the course its is direct use of that function.

Comment: Right you are.   Good luck with it.

Comment: The reason there are so many facial recog codes out there is that people have put a lot of time in to it. Bicycle recognition has its fair share of interest as well because of the whole driverless car thing, try searching that out... But really, you're going to have poop results from most code straight from the net if you don't understand the tuning parameters (which a course like zipzit suggests will get you started on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have an uphill struggle using standard techniques like contours for this.

***Edit*** >> So, using your bike example, what will happen here:

[image]

?

Neural Networks and other machine learning algorithms are your best bet instead:

[image]

Specifically of the '[Multiclass Classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification)' variety. With training (time), they stand a better chance of sorting your cats from your bicycles.

As for code examples have a look [here](http://briandolhansky.com/blog/2013/9/23/artificial-neural-nets-linear-multiclass-part-3). Not an image based example, but you need to **start somewhere** :)

Also helpful (and tested working by myself) is the [DLIB library](http://blog.dlib.net/2014/02/dlib-186-released-make-your-own-object.html):

With only 8 training images of a stop sign, its internal structure formed this representation:

[image]

Pretty nifty.

There is no reason you cant use your contours results as inputs to a ML classifier, as long as they increase the signal to noise ratio somehow... (i.e. they're somehow more 'bikey' than not)

Comment: Hi Lamar Latrell

given example of chicken and cat are not matching but 
as per my requirement it is ok that both images are same since both have same shape 

it would be helpful if u can provide me some code example

Comment: Lamer - the input files will be given by me it will consist of bike or car

Comment: @usernanny, So the set of images for comparison, and the images they are compared to are fully known beforehand?

Comment: Ya . i am sure that the image given for comparison  is either bike or car .

Comment: As per u said that contours will not give correct output ,i agree with u .
for that i will have to Use ML . But for my  application i dont req that functionality .

Comment: @usernan, contours will certainly *change* the output,and with a bit of applied smarts there is even a chance they may increase the information entropy 'with respect to the objects of interest' - i.e. cars vs. bikes - does that make sense to you? What you want to do is filter/process the data such that cars trigger one response, bikes another and everything else yet another. Kind of baking in your insight as a human. But this is what deep architecture NN's do *automatically* for you. Hence the recommendation. All that being said, I don't really understand your last comment.

Comment: Forget about last comment .
 you mean to say that i need to use ML only .
 Just tel me i can achieve this using PCA

Comment: @usernan, [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis)?  No, it's not a classifier. It's a process that gives you insight into the most 'informative' dimensions in a data-set. Often used for  dimensionality reduction (i.e. compression). If used, it would sit in a pre-processing step only.

Comment: @usernan, well, neural networks and other machine learning algorithms are your best bet, specifically of the '[Multiclass Classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification)' variety.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110465/discussion-between-lamar-latrell-and-usernan).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the following methods can be applied and tested ->

1. GF-HOG
2. Deformable Parts Model
3. Neural Networks

A combination would be an awesome idea but will GFHOG will add to overheads.

Study about it its pretty cool tech I think this will answer your query.
http://personal.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/R.Hu/ICIP.html

Comment: Ill check that out Anubhav